# Compare element between two similar array

Tags: shell-script

Suppose such a minimal task to select elements in B but not in A

```
file_list1=(a.sh b.sh c.sh)
file_list2=(b.sh c.sh d.sh)

for i in files_list1; do
    for k in files_list2; do
        if [[ $k in $(echo $i) ]]; then
        echo 
        else
        echo $k
        fi
    done
done
```

it report errors:

```
$ bash compare.sh 
compare.sh: line 5: conditional binary operator expected
compare.sh: line 5: syntax error near `in'
compare.sh: line 5: `        if [[ $k in $(echo $i) ]]; then'
```

if not apply `in`, how could get the code working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the logic, you have this syntax errors:

- It is `file_list`, not `files_list`.
- To expand to array elements you need to use "${file_list[@]}".

Try [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) before posting.

If you must do it in the shell, then try:

```
file_list1=(a.sh b.sh c.sh)
file_list2=(b.sh c.sh d.sh)

for i in "${file_list1[@]}"; do
    repeated_in_A=0
    for k in "${file_list2[@]}"; do
        if [[ $k == $i ]]; then
            repeated_in_A=1
        break 
        fi
    done
    ((repeated_in_A)) || echo "$k"
done
```